# Endless scrolling with kaminari in rails, how to render?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am following this tutorial: 
https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To:-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery

So far everything works great, but I am stuck at the last part of the tutorial.

The content in my **show.html.haml** gets rendered like this:

```
- @search_results.each do |search_result|
  =render 'search_result', :search_result=>search_result
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to translate that to **show.js.erb**, currently I have (mimicked from the tutorial)

```
$(".offers").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@search_results)) %>");
```

but that throws errors. (undefined method `model_name' for Hash:Class)

in my controller, search results is defined as:

```
@search_results =  Kaminari.paginate_array(all_search_results).page(params[:page]).per(6)
```

all_search_results is an array that gets filled with stuff from another model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= @search_results.map {|search_result| render('search_result.html', :search_result => search_result)}.to_json.html_safe %>
```

did the trick